# python: local variable lifecycle

Tags: python, garbage-collection, lifecycle, local-variables

these two snippets look the same but can give different results:

```
def foo():
    bar(get_var())
    ...
    # `var` alive?

def foo():
    var = get_var()
    bar(var)
    ...
    # `var` alive?
```

in both cases, the `...` part does not use `var`; the mere difference is the lifecycle of a local object `var`; it seems that
the object is destroyed earlier in the first snippet than the second; (the object is not explicitly named in the first snippet, but clearly it means the return value of `get_var`;)

questions:

1. in the first snippet, is it guaranteed `var` is destroyed right after `bar`
   returns? we can assume `bar` does not keep a reference to `var`;
2. in the second snippet, is it guaranteed `var` will be alive until `foo`
   returns? is the runtime clever enough to detect `var` will not be used after `bar` returns (even if it is still in scope of `foo`)?

Comment: There *is no `var`* in the first example. You seem to be equivocating between the lifecycle of a *variable* and the life cycle of an *object*. Local variables cease to exist when the function they are in terminates (or perhaps earlier, if you explicitly `del` the variable). Objects will be guaranteed to exist until their reference count reaches zero. In CPython, as an implementation detail, objects are reclaimed *immediately* when their reference count reaches zero, but other implementations (e.g. Jython) may work differently.

Comment: So, again, in your first snippet, **there is no `var`**. But the object returned by `get_var()` may or may not survive depending on what happens in `bar`. In the second case, the object returned by `get_var()` is referenced by `var`, so it will survive at least as long as `foo` is executing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my phrasing may be imprecise, but i understand there is no variable `var` in scope in first snippet; it means the object returned by `get_var`; as i said `bar` does not keep a reference to that object, so the question is actually whether runtime will destroy that object immediately after its use is over (when `bar` returns); the answer should be one of *yes*, *no*, or *maybe*;

Comment: No, not CPython. In CPython, that reference exists until the function terminates. If at the end of the function, there is no other reference, then CPython will reclaim it immediately.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga are you sure? i added `__del__` to that object and it was called when `bar` returns and before `foo` returns; i think `__del__` is called only when an object's ref count reaches 0;

Comment: To be clear, if no other references to the object exists, in case 1) The variable is destroyed when `bar` terminates (or at some point earlier depending on the details), and in case 2) when `foo` terminates.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, this is what has been observed, but no documentation proves it; actually i did not find a doc about precise control of an object lifecycle;

Comment: Because Python does not provide precise control of memory management. You can get a better understanding of Python's reference counting mechanisms if you peruse the C API docs, for example: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html

Comment: Languages with automatic memory management rarely make guarantees about precisely when an object will be destroyed after it becomes unreachable. All they guarantee is that it *won't* be destroyed before this, and they often make a best effort to destroy it shortly after it becomes garbage.

Comment: When reference counting is used, they usually can reclaim the memory immediately, but if the reference was part of a circular structure, it may have to wait for a full garbage collection.